# Hibernate 5 Multitenancy and H2 : ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Schema MYSCHEMA not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2, multi-tenant

I am using Spring Framework test configuration (legacy app)

Very strange behaviour of H2 database with Hibernate 5 multitenancy,

I just added configuration to my tests, and the spring application context can't work :

```
@Bean
    public static DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

=> [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper Schema "MYSCHEMA" not found [90079-197]
```

So i went with the usual H2 add schema.

```
    @Bean
    public static DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA MYSCHEMA");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

Schema "MYSCHEMA" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE SCHEMA MYSCHEMA[90078-197]
```

And I'm now stuck... I already tried hbm2ddl to update, I'm actually very confused...

Comment: You have DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false and then MYSCHEMA in uppercase letters

Comment: Changed it, it did not solve the problem :
I changed the config recently, I think it's because of a bad spring test configuration, i don't understand how i could have a schema at start but not after it's strange !

Comment: Seeing threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136176/add-tenant-dynamically-in-multitenant-database-application-using-spring-mvc-and), it might seem like i still have to configure a non multitenant FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory>, nobody really had this problem ever? (create drop actually doesn't work with H5 multitenancy)